# Notation for set of constant functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have a constant function that always returns the same integer value. How do I represent a set of functions where each function is a constant function that returns some arbitrary constant? For example, I would like to identify an element $f_p$ of this set as a function that always returns the integer value $p$. Similarly, $f_3$ would be a constant function that always returns $3$.

I'm also confused as to how I would define any arbitrary instance of a constant function. For example, if I had a function that always returned $2$, would I define it as $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \{2\}$?

Comment: When the domain $D$ is known, it's quite common (at least in set theory) to write $c_x$ for the constant function $c_x \colon D \to \{x\}$.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan - it looks like I wasn't far off for the notation of individual instances. How would I define the family? Would it be appropriate to define it as $\{c\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ where $c \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Write $\{c_z \mid z \in \mathbb Z\}$ instead (or something along those lines).

Comment: @Stefan Thanks! I can accept if you post your comment as the answer, since it answers my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your domain seems to be fixed throughout your argument, there is no need to make it visible to your reader. In these cases, it's quite common to write $c_x$ for the constant function $c_x \colon D \to \{x\}$, where $D$ is the fixed domain. Then
$$
\mathcal C = \{ c_x \mid x \in X \}
$$
is the collection of all constant functions with value in $X$ - for some given $X$. In your particular case,
$$
\mathcal C = \{ c_z \mid z \in \mathbb Z\}
$$
is the collection of all constant functions with integer values.